# Select an Anchor (<a>) and an ID-ed div with the same :target

Tags: css, target, pseudo-class

I'm woking on a project that heavily relies on the `:target` psuedo-class.

If the `<a>` tag has a name and that name is the text after the # and there is no other element with an id equal to the text after the #, then the a receives the :target.

That was confusing, so here's an example:

```
<style>
    * {
        color: black;
    }
    :target {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#one" name="one">one_link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#two" name="two">two_link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#three" name="three">three_link</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="one">div_one</div>
    <div id="two_div">div_two</div>
    <div id="three_div">div_three</div>
</div>
```

If you were to click on the "one_link," then "div_one" would turn red. However, if you were to click on "two_link" or "three_link," then they themselves would turn red (because there isn't a div with the id of the # string, but they have the name of the # string)

What I want is for the :target class to work on both the anchor and the div, or at least a way to select the anchor only when the div is targeted. This can probably be done with Javascript, but I'm trying to use pure css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in pure css. There's no way to "program" css to dynamically change a selector to add some extra text based on something that's been clicked. That's waaaay outside the scope of CSS. That's why there's Javascript.

Comment: I'm talking about adding text to the selector being clicked, not adding text to the dom. e.g. something like `#+click(source) { color: red }`. The OP wants CSS to somehow turn the click on `target="#two"` into `target="#two_div"` purely with CSS, which is NOT possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude the anchor selection by using `div:target`

```
  * {
        color: black;
    }
    div:target{
        color: red;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/

With the same technique you can try with `a:target` to get only the current targeted anchor

Answer (score 0):

That's not really possible.

You can't use anything like `:target ~ div`, because of your HTML structure: there is no way to select a parent element. Even if that wasn't a problem, there's no automatic way to map "nth" `a` to "nth" `div`.

With license to change the HTML, I came up with this: http://jsfiddle.net/pA84B/ - it's nasty.

Just use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

**See [Google: HTML, CSS, and Javascript from the Ground Up](http://code.google.com/edu/submissions/html-css-javascript/)**.

JavaScript is built for behavior and interaction.  The Google guys explain it well (I think), plus Google is a bit more authoritative than me.  **You *should* use JavaScript for this.**